# Count no. of matching words from one dataframe list to another dataframe list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes where i would like to count the no. of matching words from df1 to df 2

df1 is a list of keywords belonging to each sector, eg education, finance, transport etc

`df1`:

| Sector | Content |
| --- | --- |
| Education | ['school', 'children', 'learning', 'enrichment' ] |
| Finance | ['banks', 'insurance', 'moneylender'] |

df 2 is the data **scraped** from the website. Words have been split and cleaned and are in list form.

`df2`:

| Company Name | Website Info |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ['school', 'enrichment'] |
| DEF | ['banks', 'children', 'school' ] |

i want to find out the no. of words matched from each sector in df1.
Expected result:

| Company Name | Website Info | No. of Matched Words Education | No. of Matched words Finance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ['school', 'enrichment'] | 2 | 0 |
| DEF | ['banks', 'children', 'school' ] | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Loop through the lists which have a time complexity of O(n^2)

   ```
   education= ['school', 'children', 'learning', 'enrichment' ]
   abc = ['school', 'enrichment']
   count = 0
   for element in abc:
       if element in education:
           count+=1
   ```
2. To use collections.Counter() which has a time complexity of O(n)

   ```
   counters = collections.Counter(education+abc)
   count = len([x for x in list(dict(counters).values()) if x >1])
   ```

obviously the second solution is better